# Is it possible to nest synced folders in vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, puphpet

I'm developing various PHP packages in a global / shared folder, and symlinking them to various development setups, which works fine with a basic localhost setup.

However, I'm running into issues when I try to achieve the same thing inside Vagrant, as it doesn't support symlinks in synced folders (or at least has security issues).

I was advised to use synced folders to get round this, but although Vagrant tells me it's mounting the folders, when I ssh in, they are empty.

To illustrate, this is my setup:

Global packages repository (all development environments link here):

```
+- shared_drive
    +- packages
        +- PackageFoo
        +- PackageBar
        +- PackageBaz
```

Localhost (which works):

```
+- work_drive
    +- project
        +- vendor
            +- davestewart
                +- PackageFoo     <= symlink to /shared_drive/packages/PackageFoo
```

VM (which doesn't work):

```
+- vagrant
    +- project                    <= mapped to /work_drive/project
        +- vendor
            +- davestewart
                +- PackageFoo     <= mapped to /shared_drive/packages/PackageFoo
```

The paths are correct, I can `cd` everywhere.

I've tried the various sync types (default, nfs, rsync).

So no matter what I do, an `ls` in Vagrant shows `vendor/davestewart/` to be empty.

Is this even the right approach? All I want to be able to do is edit and test the original package files in all development environments I set up.

OSX / Yosemite
VirtualBox 5.1

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of any answers, I've managed to solve the problem by turning it on its head.

Rather than trying to cajole Vagrant into following an *external* symlink (which the docs themselves say is inconsistent across platforms) I've:

- Set the original external symlink `/shared_drive/packages/...` as a Vagrant synced folder
- *Internally* symlinked the original source `/project/vendor/...` to this folder

More visually:

```
+- vagrant
    +- shared
    |   +- packages               <= synced (external) folder to /shared_drive/packages/
    |       +- PackageFoo
    |       +- PackageBar
    |       +- PackageBaz
    |
    +- project
        +- vendor
            +- davestewart
                +- PackageFoo     <= symlink (internal) to /shared/packages/PackageFoo/
```

Totally easy to set up, it's fast, PHP is happy, and it should work across all OSes :)

Comment: I realize this is a super old question, but I'm wondering what happens on the host system when you symlink on the guest machine? or do you mostly ignore this locally?